# IBM Java SE 1.6 and STS conflict

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, ibm-jdk

I'm using Eclipse kepler and IBM jdk 1.6.

```
java version "1.6.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pwa6460sr2-20080818_01(SR2))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.4, J2RE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.4 Windows Vista amd64-64 jvmwa6460-20080816_22093 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - 20080816_022093_LEdSMr
JIT  - r9_20080721_1330ifx2
GC   - 20080724_AA)
JCL  - 20080808_02
```

When I install `STS for Eclipse Kepler` then following error message appears whenever I run Eclipse. Can you help me, please ?

---

```
Could not lookup required component
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:

1) Error in custom provider, java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type     javax.enterprise.inject.Typed not present
  at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
  at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
  while locating org.sonatype.plexus.components.cipher.PlexusCipher
  while locating org.sonatype.plexus.components.sec.dispatcher.DefaultSecDispatcher
  at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
  at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
  while locating org.sonatype.plexus.components.sec.dispatcher.SecDispatcher annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=maven)
  while locating org.apache.maven.settings.crypto.DefaultSettingsDecrypter
  at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
  at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
  while locating org.apache.maven.settings.crypto.SettingsDecrypter
  while locating org.apache.maven.repository.legacy.LegacyRepositorySystem
  at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
  at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
  while locating org.apache.maven.repository.RepositorySystem
  while locating org.apache.maven.execution.DefaultMavenExecutionRequestPopulator
  at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
  at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
  while locating org.apache.maven.execution.MavenExecutionRequestPopulator

1 error
      role: org.apache.maven.execution.MavenExecutionRequestPopulator
  roleHint:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
solved.
1) get websphere 7.0 for developer
2) install it.
3) get updateinstaller
4) install it.
5) get lastest fix packs for websphere 7.0 (java sdk involed)
6) update with fix packs.
7) use updated java within websphere.
```